# How to identify the object of the phrasal verb in this sentence?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I have the following sentence in my textbook:

> The floods have **cut off** several villages in the mountains.

(English Phrasal Verbs in Use, Advanced, Exercise 2.2)

It says that the following form of the same sentence is less likely as the object is quite long:

> The floods have **cut** several villages in the mountains **off**.

However, this looks odd to me. Isn’t the object here is “several villages”? Is the following form appropriate?

> The floods have **cut** several villages **off** in the mountains.

Comment: Yes: "off" is a particle that can occur between the verb and its object ("several villages ,,,") or after it.

Comment: @BillJ: I’m trying to ask whether the object is “several villages” or “several villages in the mountains” or perhaps either.

Comment: The final example here is extremely non-idiomatic, but I don't fully understand the point of the question. The reason it's "awkward" is because one adverbial element is "half-nested" within another, but that's easily fixed by *In the mountains, the floods have cut several villages off*. Even so, I *still* think most native speakers would keep the phrasal verb "intact" with *In the mountains, the floods have **cut off** several villages*. It really doesn't make any difference whether ***in the mountains*** applies to where the vilages are, or where the floods did something. It's the same thing!

Comment: What interested me is that the textbook offered a “less likely” sentence as a possible answer. The reason it’s “less likely” is the long object. So I thought why not just shorten the object and have a more likely sentence. Like if you really want to put an object between the verb and particle, why not just say *The floods have cut several villages off in the mountains* or *In the mountains, the floods have cut several villages off*.

Comment: Perhaps it wanted to emphasize *what I shouldn’t do*, not *what is possible*, and I overthink it.

Comment: Anyway, you’ve provided all the essential information I need to answer (or dismiss) the question myself. Thank you.

Comment: The object is "several villages in the mountains". The PP "in the villages" modifies villages and thus is part of the NP object.

Comment: cut off can go together OR It can go AROUND the object: cut the several villages off in the mountains.

Answer (score 0):

You want the prepositional phrase "in the mountains" to function as a modifier of "villages"  (it gives the location of the villages).  You don't want it to function adverbially to modify "cut"  (to location in which the cutting-off took place)

So it is better to keep the prepositional phrase with the NP that it modifies. It forms a new NP that functions as the object.  That is the object of the verb is "several villages in the mountains".

But note that if the PP is adverbial you might say:

> The floods cut several villages off on Tuesday.

Note the difference in function or "in the mountains" and "on Tuesday".